# collapse strings in a vector three times for an or statement in r

Tags: r, regex, rep

I have a vector with multiple strings

`strings <- c("CD4","CD8A")`

and I'd like to output an OR statement to be passed to grep like so

`"CD4-|-CD4-|-CD4$|CD8A-|-CD8A-|-CD8A$"`

and so on for each element in the vector..

basically I'm trying to find an exact word in a string that has three dashes in it, (I don't want `grep(CD4, ..)` to return strings with CD40). This is how I thought of doing it but I'm open to other suggestions

part of my data.frame looks like this:

```
Genes <- as.data.frame(c("CD4-MyD88-IL27RA", "IL2RG-CD4-GHR","MyD88-CD8B-EPOR", "CD8A-IL3RA-CSF3R", "ICOS-CD40-LMP1"))
colnames(Genes) <- "Genes"
```

Comment: Can you just split on the dash character and then check if the thing you want is in there

Comment: I tried that, when I do grep by "CD4" I also get rows with CD40 and when I do grep by "CD4$" I don't get any rows, maybe my syntax is wrong?
Here's the whole thing for reference:
`Lib_aggregated[grep("CD4$", strsplit(Lib_aggregated$Genes, "-")),]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-liner...

```
Genes$Genes[grep(paste0("\\b",strings,"\\b",collapse="|"),Genes$Genes)]

[1] "CD4-MyD88-IL27RA" "IL2RG-CD4-GHR"    "CD8A-IL3RA-CSF3R"
```

It uses word-boundary markers `\\b` to make sure that it matches complete substrings (as the `-` does not count as part of a word).

Comment: ah it was the \\b that I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood. If I got it, the following command will return what you want

```
stringr::str_split(Genes$Genes, pattern = '-') %>% 
  purrr::map(
    function(data) {
      data[stringr::str_which(data, pattern = '^CD')]
    }
  )  %>% unlist
```